# Use gstreamer to play 2 clips but direct each's audio into distinct audio channel

Tags: audio, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have a need to be able to simultaneously play 2 different video clips, downmix their audio to mono, and play the audio into the left/right channels respectively. In other words, play clip 1's audio into the left channel, and play clip 2's audio into the right channel.

Comment: What should be done with the 2 videos?

Comment: The two videos are to be played, but with the audio from the first on the left channel output and the audio from the second on the right channel output.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses audioconvert to downmix the clip to mono and then feeds it to audiopanorama to alter the balance.

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:<video file to play> audio-sink="audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,channels=1 ! audiopanorama panorama=-1 ! pulsesink"
```

panorama=-1 shifts the balance to full left while a value of 1 shift the balance to full right.

Answer (score 0):

You want everything in the same pipeline to have them all synchronized with the same clock. Try something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///file1 name=src1 ! queue ! audioconvert ! "audio/x-raw, channels=1" ! interleave name=audiointerleave ! queue ! autoaudiosink uridecodebin uri=file:///file2 name=src2 ! queue ! audioconvert ! "audio/x-raw, channels=1" ! audiointerleave. src1. ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink src2. ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

You can also consider replacing the queues after uridecodebins with multiqueue.

`audioconvert` will be able to downmix to mono and then you combine them into a single stereo stream with `interleave`